# i added a list box in asp.net , i need to get the option set values from ms crm to list box

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm

I am new to ASP.Net I added a list box in asp.net , I need to get the option set values from ms crm to list box

I don't know how to return the value for this can anybody help me

```
public static string GetMtefrecord()
{ 
    var service = CRMWrapper.GetCRMService();

    RetrieveEntityRequest retrieveBankAccountEntityRequest = new RetrieveEntityRequest
    {
        EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Entity,
        LogicalName = "tec_new_mtfmtir",
    };
    RetrieveEntityResponse retrieveBankAccountEntityResponse = (RetrieveEntityResponse)service.Execute(retrieveBankAccountEntityRequest);
    //return retrieveBankAccountEntityResponse.LogicalName.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your optionset is a global optionset, you can retrieve it using the RetrieveOptionSetRequest message. Here is a bit of sample code

```
RetrieveOptionSetRequest retrieveOptionSetRequest =
new RetrieveOptionSetRequest
{
    Name = _globalOptionSetName //Put your optionsetname here
};

// Execute the request.
RetrieveOptionSetResponse retrieveOptionSetResponse =
    (RetrieveOptionSetResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(
    retrieveOptionSetRequest);

OptionMetadata[] optionList =
     ((OptionSetMetadata) retrieveOptionSetResponse.OptionSetMetadata).Options.ToArray();
```